# How to convert ASPNetIdentity to OpenIdConnect

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have a project that uses .NET Framework 4.6 AspNetIdentity, and I'm trying to upgrade it to use OpenIdConnect. Has anyone had any success replacing ASPNetIdentity with OpenIdConnect using .NET Framework 4.6?

I've looked into owin examples and some .NET core 2.0 quickstart samples such as [these](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/Quickstarts), but they seem to be incompatible with what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm trying to specifically add something resembling the following code snippet taken from one of the above samples:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
});
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

        options.Authority = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ClientId = "foo";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

        options.Scope.Add("api1");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    });
```

I need something similar to this AddAuthentication() extension of the IServiceCollection services parameter in the ConfigureServices() method of my Startup.cs file to be able to allow a client to login via IdentityServer4.

Comment: What issues are you running into with the referenced code?  IdentityServer4 does some pretty good logging of its handling of the request to the Output window if you're running it locally in Visual Studio.  Can you see any errors being logged there? Is your request actually making it to the identity server?

Comment: @jbeanky The above code works perfectly fine in a .Net core 2.0 project, however I'm trying to replicate this functionality in a .Net Framework 4.6 project and that is where I'm running into errors. The AddAuthentication extension method in .Net Framework uses a SharedAuthenticationOptions class whereas the AddAuthentication method in .Net core 2.0 uses a AuthenticationOptions class. They both have different getters and setters and I don't know if that's the issue, I just need to get OpenId Connect to work with .Net Framework 4.6.

Comment: Check out this documentation for configuring clients to IdentityServer3.  It should be mostly the same since both follow the same specification.  https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses! I would say @Nan Yu probably had the answer that ended up being closest to the solution that I came up with, but I figured I'd share what I ultimately ended up going with in the Configure() method of my Startup.cs file.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
...
var openidOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions(authenticationScheme)
{
    ClientSecret = secret,
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    SignInScheme = "Identity.External",
    Authority = identityServerAddress,
    ClientId = clientId,
    RequireHttpsMetadata = true,
    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
    AutomaticChallenge= true,
    GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
    SaveTokens = true,
    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRemoteSignOut = async remoteSignOutContext =>
        {
            remoteSignOutContext.HttpContext.Session.Clear();
        },
    },
};
openidOptions.Scope.Clear();
openidOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openidOptions);
```

Adding this to my .NET Framework 4.6 client ended up letting me communicate with my .NET Core 2.0 Identity Server successfully! I appreciate everyone that tried to help :)

Answer (score 1):

In .net framework , you can config the OpenID Connect using `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect` library in `Startup.Auth.cs` file, something like :

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    //
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                    //
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }

            });
    }

    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.HandleResponse();
        context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```